# How do I change the background to a linear-gradient background?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Hi I am new to html and css, and i am unable to to get a linear gradient background.

This is what i am trying to get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewkO6.png

This is what i have so far

```
    body{
background-color: linear-gradient( rgb(35, 166, 252), white);}
```

The HTML code is basically empty:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="aboutme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Document</title>
<h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
</head>
<body>lorem ipsum</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `background-image:linear-gradient( rgb(35, 166, 252), white);` instead of background-color
Your problem will be solved

so your css should be

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(35, 166, 252), white);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this in your CSS code, with the following value:

```css
background: linear-gradient(45deg, black, transparent);
```